# How to detect package losses and gaps with UDP publisher to QuestDb?

Tags: udp, questdb

I am using QuestDb with UDP Influx Line Protocol publisher and want to see if there are gaps in the metrics due to package loss or any other reason.

Is there anything I can do on a publisher side or questdb to monitor the percentage of data loss if any?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do on the producer side is tag & sequence each publisher

- The tag has to be unique to a publisher
- The sequence can be a `long` value that is monotonically incremented and (ideally) the sequence number should not be reset when a publisher restarts

On the server side you can execute the following query, assuming you have the column names `tag` and `seq` for tag and sequence respectively

```sql
(SELECT a.tag, a.seq high, b.seq low 
 FROM tab a 
 ASOF JOIN tab b ON (tag)) 
WHERE high > low + 1;
```